# how to allow passing in a => AnyRef function and call that function

Tags: scala, scala-2.9

I have the following code

```
class LazyLogRecord(
  level: javalog.Level,
  messageGenerator: => AnyRef
     ) extends LogRecord(level, "") {

  // for each logged line, generate this string only once, regardless of how many handlers  there are:
  override lazy val getMessage : String = messageGenerator().toString
}
```

This code does not compile because I try to invoke messageGenerator.  I can modify the code from

```
messageGenerator: => AnyRef
to
messageGenerator: () => AnyRef
```

but then my upstream code log.debug("hi there"+variable+"asfdsaf") does not compile unless I change that code to log.debug( () => {"hi there"+variable+"asdfas"} )

If I just stick with messageGenerator.toString, the getMessage is returning "function0" instead of the invoked function results with toString called on that result.

How can I fix this to have the best of both worlds?

EDIT:
Very odd, I just modified the code to this

```
override lazy val getMessage : String = {
   val funkyThing : () => AnyRef = messageGenerator
   funkyThing().toString
}
```

and it says mesasgeGenerator is type "AnyRef" when it should say type "=> AnyRef".  It then complains it can't convery "AnyRef" to "() => AnyRef"

what is going on there?  That isn't right either.

EDIT 2: 
I am beginning to think it is a client problem.  My client code may be wrong.  My client code was like this where I pass in a function that is passed down to LazyLogRecord....is my definition of function wrong?  I think it is as then I pass it to => AnyRef and it's not exactly that same type but I needed to test the lazy evaluation out and it failed.

```
  val logger = Logger.get("lazyTest2")
  logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG)
  var executed = false
  val function = () => {
    executed = true
    "asdf"+executed+" hi there"
  }


  logger.debugLazy(function)
  assert(!executed)
```

thanks,
Dean

Comment: I deleted my answer since it was incorrect, I hope somebody else can share some light on this.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to try though ;).

Comment: I suppose it has something to do with the fact that you are calling `toString` on a function definition (and not its result), but that is just guessing.

Comment: The behavior you are describing is very strange and sounds like it could be a bug. I am unable to reproduce it. Can you provide a self-contained runnable example that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: @EndeNeu yes, which is why I tried doing messageGenerator().toString which doesn't work :(

Comment: Defining `getMessage` as `messageGenerator.toString`, properly using it as a by-name function, works correctly for me too, returning the result of whatever function I passed in as opposed to '<function0>'.  I am using Scala 2.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your latest update, changing your call to:

```
val logger = Logger.get("lazyTest2")
logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG)
var executed = false


logger.debugLazy({
  executed = true
  "asdf"+executed+" hi there"
})
```

Should fix your issue.  Your previous code is being interpreted as:

```
logger.debugLazy({function})
```

which is a function that returns your function0 as it's result which is not what you wanted.  You could also try defining `function` as a def instead of a val like so:

```
def function() = {
  executed = true
  "asdf"+executed+" hi there"
} 
logger.debugLazy(function)
```

and that should work as well.

Comment: This post is slightly related and I am wondering why one piece compiles and the other one doesn't... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272913/what-is-the-difference-between-different-function-creations