# What is the difference between different function creations

Tags: scala, scala-2.9

This question is heavily related to my other question (and may lead to me solving that one) but is definetely different.

[how to allow passing in a => AnyRef function and call that function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270193/how-to-allow-passing-in-a-anyref-function-and-call-that-function)

I have been playing with different function creations and I am frankly having trouble creating an anonymous function of type => AnyRef and => String.  I can create a function of type () => AnyRef and () => String I think.

Example 1
  I have the following code

```
def debugLazyTest2(msg: => String) : Unit = {
  System.out.println(msg)
}

//and client code
  val function: () => String = () => {
    executed = true
    "asdf"+executed+" hi there"
  }
  log2.debugLazyTest2(function)
```

but the compile error says found: () => String which makes sense but then says "required: String" instead of "required: => String"

What is going on here?

Example 2 to get even more bizarre, I have this code which compiles while above did not compile

```
def debugLazyTest(msg: => AnyRef) : Unit = {
  System.out.println(msg.toString)
}

//and client code which compiles!!!!
  val function: () => AnyRef = () => {
    executed = true
    "asdf"+executed+" hi there"
  }
  log2.debugLazyTest(function)
```

This code compiles though it doesn't work the way I would like as the library can't seem to invoke the function before toString is called (that is in my other thread and is a separate question).

Any ideas as to what is going on here?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrote this it would work:

```
log2.debugLazyTest2(function())
```

msg is a by-name parameter, not a function. You have to pass in an expression of type String (or AnyRef in the second example)

The second example compiles because the () => AnyRef you pass in is actually also an AnyRef, since a function is an AnyRef. But then it is the function itself that is printed, not the result of executing it.

Comment: this is great.  I didn't realize that was syntax for by-name and thought it was passing in a function.  This clears things up for me now......thanks much!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following code:

```
scala> def test(x: String) = debugLazyTest2(x)
test: (x: String)Unit
```

If we then run (in Scala 2.11.2):

```
:javap test
```

And trim a bit of the generated output, we see the following:

```
  public void test(java.lang.String);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=4, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: getstatic     #19                 // Field .MODULE$:L;
         3: new           #21                 // class $anonfun$test$1
         6: dup
         7: aload_1
         8: invokespecial #23                 // Method $anonfun$test$1."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        11: invokevirtual #27                 // Method .debugLazyTest2:(Lscala/Function0;)V
        14: return
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0      15     0  this   L;
               0      15     1     x   Ljava/lang/String;
      LineNumberTable:
        line 8: 0
```

And then we consider the signature for `debugLazyTest2`:

```
 public void debugLazyTest2(scala.Function0<java.lang.String>);
```

The key line is:

```
         3: new           #21                 // class $anonfun$test$1
```

If I am reading the code correctly, we are instantiating a new instance of the class `$anonfun$test$1` - and passing that new anonymous `Function0[String]` to `debugLazyTest2`. This makes our `test` method equivalent to the following:

```
def test(x: String) = debugLazyTest2(new Function0[String] {
    def apply(): String = x
})
```

When we consider passing in an instance of `Function0[String]` to `debugLazyTest2` making the same transformation, we get:

```
debugLazyTest2(function)
```

which becomes:

```
debugLazyTest2(new Function0[String] {
    def apply(): Function0[String] = function
})
```

which, of course, does not compile, because `apply(): Function0[String]` does not match the required type `apply(): String` (hence the error message).

Actually *invoking* the function instead of returning it works:

```
debugLazyTest2(function())
```

becomes:

```
debugLazyTest2(new Function0[String] {
    def apply(): String = function()
})
```